# Generate a sequence of names such as a1, a2, a3

Tags: string-manipulation

How do I generate the sequency `{disp1, disp2, disp3, ...}`?

I tried the following but it didn't give me what I expected:

```
List1=Table[JoinString["disp","i"],{i,1,5}]
```

This gives the list `{dispi,dispi,dispi,dispi,dispi}`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use `ToString[i]` in `Table` otherwise you'll get what you say, i.e. "i" literally.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basics of the site. Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it seems to be a
[duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates). Read the links to understand what this is about. If you think that would be a mistake, please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to [improve it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and make it more specific.

Answer (score 1):

use [`StringJoin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringJoin.html) instead of `JoinString` and [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html)

```
list1 = Table[StringJoin["disp", ToString[i]], {i, 1, 5}]
```

> ```
> {"disp1", "disp2", "disp3", "disp4", "disp5"}
> ```

Comment: Thank you...I should have thought about that.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
Range[5] /. n_Integer :> StringJoin[{"disp", ToString@n}]
```